# Confused about matrix and vector operations, properties.

Tags: linear-algebra

I am currently studying topics in Machine Learning and came across a solution I do not fully understand. The problem #4a, the statement and solution can be found here: http://cs229.stanford.edu/materials/ps1sol.pdf

The specific part I am confused about is the simplification of the denominator,

$-\frac{1}{2}(x - \mu_0)^T \Sigma^{-1} (x - \mu_0)+\frac{1}{2}(x - \mu_1)^T \Sigma^{-1} (x - \mu_1)\\
=-\frac{1}{2}(x^T\Sigma^{-1}x - \mu_0^T\Sigma^{-1}x - x^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu_0 + \mu_0^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu_0 - x^T\Sigma^{-1}x + \mu_1^T\Sigma^{-1}x + x^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu_1 - \mu_1^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu_1)\\
=-\frac{1}{2}(\mu_0^T\Sigma^{-1}x - (x^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu_0)^T + \mu_0^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu_0 + \mu_1^T\Sigma^{-1}x + (x^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu_1)^T - \mu_1^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu_1)$

How is it that $x^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu_1 = (x^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu_1)^T$?

Also, I am having a hard time convincing myself that,

$(x - \mu_0)^T \Sigma^{-1} (x - \mu_0) = x^T \Sigma^{-1} x - x\Sigma^{-1}\mu_0 - \mu_0\Sigma^{-1}x + \mu_0\Sigma^{-1}\mu_0$

Does it not matter if $\Sigma^{-1}$ is diagonal or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your first question, note that $x^{T}\Sigma^{-1}\mu_{1}$ is a dot product, hence a real number. In particular, $x^{T}\Sigma^{-1}\mu_{1} = x\cdot\Sigma^{-1}u$. But for any real number $r$, it is the case that $r=r^{T}$, so $x^{T}\Sigma^{-1}\mu_{1}=\left(x^{T}\Sigma^{-1}\mu_{1}\right)^{T}.$

For the second part, use the distributive and associative properties. Indeed,
\begin{align}(x-\mu_0)^{T}\Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu_0)&=(x^{T}-\mu_0^{T})\left(\Sigma^{-1}x-\Sigma^{-1}\mu_0\right)\\&=x^{T}\Sigma^{-1}x-x^{T}\Sigma^{-1}\mu_0-\mu_{0}^{T}\Sigma^{-1}x + \mu_{0}\Sigma^{-1}\mu_{0}.\end{align}